# NSTimer - Stopwatch

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've trying to create a stopwatch with HH:MM:SS, code is as follows:

```
-(IBAction)startTimerButton;
{
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(IBAction)stopTimerButton;
{
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}


-(void)showActivity;
{
    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + 1;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2i:%.2i:%.2i", newTime];
}
```

Although the output does increment by 1 second as expected the format of the output is XX:YY:ZZZZZZZZ , where XX are the seconds.

Anyone any thoughts ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your stringWithFormat asks for 3 integers but you're only passing in one ;)

Here is some code that I've used before to do what I think you're trying to do :

```
- (void)populateLabel:(UILabel *)label withTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeInterval {
    uint seconds = fabs(timeInterval);
    uint minutes = seconds / 60;
    uint hours = minutes / 60;

    seconds -= minutes * 60;
    minutes -= hours * 60;

    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%02uh:%02um:%02us", (timeInterval<0?@"-":@""), hours, minutes, seconds]];
}
```

to use it with a timer, do this :

```
    ...
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    ...

- (void)updateTimer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    currentTime += 1;
    [self populateLabel:myLabel withTimeInterval:time;
}
```

where currentTime is a NSTimeInterval that you want to count up by one every second.

Comment: Thanks, YY, ZZ, was the format that was being displayed with the above code. But I've changed it to:

time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i", second/(60*60), second/60, second];

based on what you suggest and the format is not HH:MM:SS but my seconds stop counting after 1. Any ideas ?

Comment: The first line of your method is [time.text intValue] - there isn't an intValue of a string like HH:MM:SS so intValue returns 0 every time. You need to add a variable to your class to store the currentTime. See my edit for some code I've used before to do this.